# newFixedThreadPool active threads number

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an issue this is snippet of my code

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

int count = 0;

while(true){
    if(count < 10){
        runner = new Runner();
        futures.add(executor.submit(runner));
        count++;
    }
    else{
        count = 0;
        for(f:futures){
            while(!f.isDone()){sleep(1000);}
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }
}
```

The runner does a finite amount of work. when I do a

```
ps -eLf  | grep pid | wc -l
```

I see thousands of thread for the process and the cpu load is increasing constantly. Any explanation?

Comment: Where do you `shutdown` the `ExecutorService`? If you do not then it is absolutely no surprise...

Comment: My guess is you call this code many times and don't shutdown the executor between calls.  You should be reusing the same executor each time of course.

Comment: I have actually tried the shutdown ... if you shutdown is the problem let me try to ensure that shutdown is done

Comment: Why are the waiting and the executor termination done inside the loop?

Comment: Because i don't even want to submit a lot of jobs to the executor. @EyalSchneider

Comment: @sethi: then use a for loop to add 10 tasks, and then do a second loop to wait for the tasks to complete. Otherwise the outer loop is repeated over and over, creating new pools (is that what you need?)

Comment: Actually that's what i want i have this long running java process which will pick input files and process(this part is ignored). so i want 10 files to be processed and another files to be picked for processing (lets say runner picks a new input file internally). @EyalSchneider

Comment: Your API is strange. Did you mean Executors.newFixedThreadPool(..)? also, what is the type of f? done() isn't a standard method of Future.

Comment: Your usage for the `ExecutorService` API is wrong. Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You are, for some unknown reason, creating new instances of the `ExecutorService`. You are, for some unknown reason, not using `invokeAll`. You are, for some unknown reason, using `sleep` in a nested loop rather than blocking. All in all, I can't see a single line of this code that is _correct_. Even the formatting is wrong.

Comment: I tried reproducing this using your code (which should be optimized), and I don't see the number of threads increasing. Anyway, note that you have a memory leak. Remember to remove all items from your futures collection before starting over.

Comment: This is a smaller version of code which i have just typed to show the issue not saying its production quality code. Though invokeall is a good idea your comment does not help in anyways explaining anything about why the thread count is increasing which was my question  @BoristheSpider

Comment: @sethi: Please try the code snippet (with a dummy task) - you'll see that there's no increase in the threads count. Probably the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @EyalSchneider thanks let me try that also i would try looking at all the thread names may be that will help...are you running the same ps command to check the thread count?

Comment: @sethi: Yes, i'm using the same command.